# How to add an item to an arraylist of object via a foreach loop?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a Team class something like this: (Constructor)

```
public Teams(String managerName, ArrayList<Employee> directReportEmployees){
    this.managerName = managerName;
    this.directReportEmployees = directReportEmployees;
}
```

My goal here is to add an employee to a list of team whose manager is 'John'. To do this, I am looping through the list of teams to find the team with the manager name 'John' and then adding an employee to the list of employees with the manager 'John'.

```
for (Teams team : TeamsList) {
    if (team.managerName.equals("John")){
        team.directReportEmployees.add(emp1);
       //assume emp1 is an object type Employee.
    }
}
```

This is how the arraylist of teams was generated.

```
        ArrayList<Employee> sampleList= new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Teams> TeamsList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Employee employee : employeesList) {
            Teams team = new Teams(employee.firstName, sampleList);
            TeamsList.add(team);
        }
```

However, when I do this, this adds the employee to all of the teams. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How did you create the lists ? please share as much code as needed so we can reproduce that

Comment: I have added it in, please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Share code to make a **reproducible** example, so we can just copy and run it, that isn't enough, we need all the variable definitions

Comment: Shouldn’t `Teams` be named in the singular? Does that class represent a single team or many?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created the list of Employee once `ArrayList<Employee> sampleList= new ArrayList<>();` and adding it to all the teams, the **same instance**, each team share the exact same list, so when adding to one, you see it in each

You need to create a new list for each Team

```
List<Teams> TeamsList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Employee employee : employeesList) {
    Teams team = new Teams(employee.firstName, new ArrayList<>());
    TeamsList.add(team);
}
```

Also as class `Teams` represent **one** team, it should be named `Team` at singular

Answer (score 1):

So, this happens when you instantiate your teams array with the same ArrayList.

You have not provided full code, But im assuming this is your current code

```
ArrayList<Employee> sampleList= new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Teams> TeamsList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Employee employee : employeesList) {
        Teams team = new Teams(employee.firstName, sampleList);
        TeamsList.add(team);
    }
```

change that to

```
    ArrayList<Teams> TeamsList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Employee employee : employeesList) {
        Teams team = new Teams(employee.firstName, new ArrayList<>());
        TeamsList.add(team);
    }
```

Comment: Your code isn't valid and so doesn't compile, take a look ;) (other than the 'psvm' shortcut)

Comment: i have updated the one line after reading your code which was not there before. Run and check

Comment: Instance variable names should start with lowercase.